# How do I display database trigger errors on a web application through Payara5

Tags: java, sql, payara

This is a standard error I receive for all Errors parsed from Database Triggers. I use `Payara5` as the Application Server and `Netbeans 8.2 IDE`. In the instance on the picture, it was supposed to display **"ID Number mandatory for applicants order that 18 years of age"**.

How do I make sure that the exact error as in the trigger, appears on the Web Application?

[image]

Comment: Is the error from the trigger visible in the log file of Payara? If yes then you probably need to call `getCause()` on the `LocalTransactionException`. Posting the output from the log file would be better than a screenshot. ;)

Comment: @ChristophJohn -- This is the error from the Payara Log:

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:** >>ID Number is mandatory for Applicants older than 18 years.**
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262) 


And this is the Exception handling part of code:
 } catch (Exception ex) { JSFUtils.addMessageSessionError(ExceptionUtils.formatException(AdHocTools.getCurrentMethodName(), ExceptionUtils.findRootException(ex).getMessage()));
        }

Answer (score 0):

Given your stacktrace it looks like you need to remove the `ExceptionUtils.findRootException(ex).getMessage()` and just use `ex.getMessage()` since the thrown topmost Exception already contains the message that you need.

I would try with the following code when an Exception is thrown:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    JSFUtils.addMessageSessionError(
        ExceptionUtils.formatException(AdHocTools.getCurrentMethodName(),
        ex.getMessage());
}
```

However, `ExceptionUtils.findRootException(ex).getMessage()` might be there for a reason. There are cases where the topmost `Exception` is pretty general (e.g. an `EJBException`) and you really need to get to the root exception to get a meaningful message.

You could also try with this code which returns an `SQLException` if applicable and in other cases the root Exception.

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    Throwable rootCause = ex;
    while (rootCause.getCause() != null && rootCause.getCause() != rootCause) {
        if ( rootCause instanceof java.sql.SQLException ) {
            break;
        }
        rootCause = rootCause.getCause();
    }
    JSFUtils.addMessageSessionError(
        ExceptionUtils.formatException(AdHocTools.getCurrentMethodName(),
            rootCause.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.payara-p2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: **>>You are not authorized to verify this record.**
Error Code: 50000
The bolded error is the one I want displayed at the System Application as an error, instead of **Error: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.**.

Comment: From where is that exception-handling code? Is it from the UI-side, e.g. JSF page? If yes, then we misunderstood each other. The improved exception-handling code needs to be where the access to the entity manager is made. Searching for the root cause of the Exception in JSF code will probably not work since you probably do not get all the Exceptions that were thrown but only one.

Comment: The exception is in an EJB, where I also planted the improved exception handling. With the first one, it still does not view the error as is on the db trigger.
And the second gives the error in Netbeans: package com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception does not exist even when I do an import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I changed it to use the general java.sql.SQLException which specific SQLExceptions (e.g. for MSSQL) should extend. If it still does not work: which Exception do you receive now?

Comment: Still gives the same as in the above picture.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but you did recompile and redeploy the new version to Payara? ;) Just asking, sometimes forget to do it myself. Otherwise could you please **attach** the complete stack trace (or log file) to the question?

Comment: Ran into a new problem as I change to compile with Payara5 now all my javax.* imports are in errors and cannot clean and build successfully see below:
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

Comment: Hmm how did you compile before? I think you need to add Payara or javaee dependencies as `provided` if you use maven.